# Cannot access the Internet even though ethernet is connected? DHCP problem

Tags: networking, server, internet, network-manager, dhcp

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo z500 laptop. I use the same laptop at my work and at my home. MY work place uses a static IP so I have to manually set my IP address in the network manager and when I go home I turn it back to DHCP (automatic) this usually works fine.

But yesterday due to some problem I cannot edit my network connections so I searched online and tried bunch of things none of them worked but after a reboot I could edit my connections and changed my ipv4 settings manually and everything was fine  but when I went back home and turned it back to DHCP it stopped working but I can connect to the internet at my work by setting manually.

My guess is I screwed up something while attempting all the solutions the other day, I  tried to revert all the changes made but I don't remember all the things I tried so any suggestion would be appreciated.

PS: I checked and the internet at my home is working fine the problem is with my laptop.

PPS: If not a solution at least say how I can factory reset my setting (only network settings if possible).

*If you require any output from my side please comment I will add it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole NetworkManager configurations are stored in the folder `/etc/NetworkManager`.
If you look around in the files in there there will be a file called `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` this file is for you general configurations.

The default content of that file is

> [main]
> plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
>
> [ifupdown]
> managed=true

If that doesn't help. You could always try using the `/etc/network/interfaces` directly instead of using the networkmanager. See [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man5/interfaces.5.html) for a manuel.

Comment: i have already tried the first one it didn't work.if no other answers solves the issue i will use the second one

Comment: If you know how to set up you configuration manually in the interfaces without issues you could reset your NetworkManager by purging it. with sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager network-manager-* && sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager

Comment: thanks i think this might help and the contents of my NetworkManager.conf  are like [link](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/17111302/) this should i change them back to default

Comment: Oh, you have to have managed=true or the network-manager won't do anything ;) - change that and restart the service `sudo service network-manager restart `

Comment: i corrected it and i was asking abt the middle 2 line ' dns=dnsmasq' and 'no-auto-default=20:89:84:E2:17:4D' should i remove them

Comment: You can leave that, it's the default value for it. However your "no-auto-default" also blocks automatic configuration for any ethernet port with the MAC that is listed there. You could remove that too.